# Finding distance through pair of points

Tags: list-manipulation

I have 2 sets of data of points in 3D space. What I want to do is to find the minimum distance of pair of points from each set (so basically how close the sets can get to each other). For example, say

```
fst = {{2.22673,0.59492,2.6842},{3.13408,0.16181,1.63544}, 
       {1.34213,-0.31185,3.25682},{3.11765,-1.15956,1.2044},
       {3.21693,-1.46205,-0.21326},{3.25025,1.24013,0.66829},
       {3.34529,0.95071,-0.68805},{3.32838,-0.43039,-1.13854},
       {-0.45219,1.37427,3.23023},{0.47229,2.32191,2.63187}}
sec = {{9.22673,0.59492,2.6842},{10.1341,0.16181,1.63544},
       {8.34213,-0.31185,3.25682},{10.1177,-1.15956,1.2044},
       {10.2169,-1.46205,-0.21326},{10.2503,1.24013,0.66829},
       {10.3453,0.95071,-0.68805},{10.3284,-0.43039,-1.13854},
       {6.54781,1.37427,3.23023},{7.47229,2.32191,2.63187}}
```

What I did was to first create list of all pairs

```
perm = Outer[List, fst, sec]
```

Then I applied the list to function `EuclideanDistance[]`

```
Min[EuclideanDistance @@ perm]
```

This apparently didn't work, because the distance function doesn't know how to read the coordinates. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: `Min[Outer[EuclideanDistance, fst, sec, 1]]` You need to specify the level (4th argument) in `Outer`. Check out the docs.

Comment: For large point sets it is more efficient to work with `Nearest`, like so. `In[22]:= nf1 = Nearest[fst];
candidates = nf1[sec][[All, 1]];
mindist = Min[MapThread[EuclideanDistance, {sec, candidates}]]

Out[24]= 3.95815195623`

Comment: Ah, good point. Thank you!

Comment: Alternatively: `Min@DistanceMatrix[fst, sec]`.